# extended information in asp.net membership profile

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-membership

I'm currently developing a web site that will make heavy use of asp.net membership. (Using Umbraco, but that just uses the regular asp.net membership provider).
I want to store some extended information about a user and I'm considering if I should store the information in the profile or in a custom table. Is there any pros / cons to any specific method? Some properties like payment details are more natural to place in the profile, on the other hand, a transaction log seems less natural residing in the user profile (IMHO). Any thoughts on this?
Any experience with asp.net membership?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just extend the Membership providor to include the additional infromation. You may want to build your a custom membership provider to replace the standard one, it just means inheriting from the standard one and in your case, possibly just a matter of adding addtional members.

I would also personally not ever use the Profile Provider and just extend the Membership provider.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Do you think the membership provider / profile is a good place to store a transaction log? Isn't creating a seperate table to handle this type of data a better solution? pros / cons?

Comment: yes, sorry read that bit correctly, the membership provider should only use the memebership part of your Users/Contact table and other info you need to hand. You should create a separate table for transactions and have that as a separate entitiy to the Membership.

Comment: Yep, that was what I was thinking, just wanted to see if there are other points of view. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using a custom table to store the information.

Pros:

1. Seperation of SQL Tables
2. Will keep maintainence simple of the membership database need to be reinstalled etc..
3. Will have no changes to standard Membership SPs etc..
4. No need to write custom provider...

For the transactional Log - Go ahead with a seperate table even if you chose to use Membership provider. It will give you the pros as listed above...

In your example you quoted using Payment Details etc.. I am sure you will consider encryption for sensitive data..

Comment: I do encrypt data, but this can be done on a column-by-column basis, if the logic is implemented in the DAL and not in the DB itself. In my implementation the DB only sees encrypted values and the presentation layer only sees textual data. The DAL is the only component that sees both and we put security efforts into that specific component.

Comment: Oh... and thanks for the comment. I was leaning that way as well.